# Add text to existing PDF using Python and PDFTron

Tags: pdf, text, pdftron

I’m trying to add text dynamically to an existing PDF with a font available in the system using pdfnetpython3 9.1.0 from the PDFTron SDK. I’m using the following Python code:

```
texts = ["test1", "test2"]
ewriter = ElementWriter()
ebuilder = ElementBuilder()
# not shown here: create PDFDoc object from PDF in disk
page = pdf_doc.GetPage(3)
ewriter.Begin(page)
element = ebuilder.CreateTextBegin(Font.Create(pdf_doc.GetSDFDoc(), "Inter", ""), 11)
ewriter.WriteElement(element)
for i, text in enumerate(texts):
    element = ebuilder.CreateTextRun(text)
    element.SetTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20*i)
    ewriter.WriteElement(element)
    i += 1
element = ebuilder.CreateTextEnd()
ewriter.WriteElement(element)
ewriter.End()  # save changes to the current page
```

However, the text shows up in Japanese characters in the saved PDF. Am I loading the font incorrectly by passing its name and an empty string as char_set ? I’ve followed the sample that loads the Helvetica font in https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/py/UnicodeWriteTest .

I have tried to call [PDFNet.AddFontSubst()](https://www.pdftron.com/api/uwp/guides/html/daa96099-5d4b-fb76-eeca-76dd5206a0d0.htm) with the Inter font file path as parameter before rendering the strings, but I got the same result.

I’m only able to load the font correctly if I provide a Font.StandardType1Font (e.g. Font.e_times_roman) instead of a font name to [Font.Create()](https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFTronSDK/dotnetcore/pdftron.PDF.Font.html#methods) (this links to the .NET sdk, but .NET and Python SDK uses the same classes and methods names).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but A is not an option. I can look into B into the future, but my first priority is to make the dynamic text creation work using a font from the system. My local dev system and the server that will process the PDF documents have the font in question installed. It seems that the issue is that it was not loaded correctly into PDFTron.

Comment: Are you using a Linux system? If so, it please check to see if fontconfig is installed. You can also use the method CreateTrueTypeFont method and pass the font file directly. Please see the following API for details (C++ API is the same as Python): https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFTronSDK/cpp/classpdftron_1_1_p_d_f_1_1_font.html#a654abed2f8427fad78b6bb02fb2dfefd